Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.apache.flink.types.Row.getFieldNames(boolean)" because "from" is null
I try to implement Apache Flink jdbc codes which read data from Apache Kafka and insert them into MySQL. First I make simple codes which read data from Kafka single topic and insert into MySQL single table. Below are the codes.
from title_flink_stream import TITLE_FLINK_STREAM
 
from pyflink.common import WatermarkStrategy, Types, SimpleStringSchema, Row
from pyflink.common.typeinfo import RowTypeInfo
from pyflink.datastream import StreamExecutionEnvironment
from pyflink.datastream.connectors.jdbc import JdbcConnectionOptions, JdbcExecutionOptions, JdbcSink
from pyflink.datastream.connectors.kafka import KafkaSource, KafkaOffsetsInitializer
from pyflink.datastream.functions import MapFunction 

from pyflink.datastream.functions import MapFunction 
 
import configparser 
import os

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
        
path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
os.chdir(path)

config.read('resources/SystemConfig.ini')

env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.get_execution_environment()
env.set_parallelism(1)

env.add_jars('file:///home/joseph/flink/jars/flink-connector-kafka-3.1.0-1.18.jar', 
        'file:///home/joseph/flink/jars/kafka-clients-3.8.0.jar',
        'file:///home/joseph/flink/jars/flink-connector-jdbc-3.1.2-1.18.jar',
        'file:///home/joseph/flink/jars/mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar')

class CustomCsvMapFunction(MapFunction):
    def map(self, value):
        str_list = value.split(',')
        # return Types.ROW(str_list)
        if str_list[0] != '' and str_list[1] != '':
            return Row(date=str_list[0], value=float(str_list[1]), state=str_list[2], id=str_list[3], title=str_list[4], frequency_short=str_list[5],\
                units_short=str_list[6], seasonal_adjustment_short=str_list[7])
    

kafka_brokerlist = config['KAFKA_CONFIG']['kafka.brokerlist']

mysql_user = config['MYSQL_CONFIG']['mysql.user']
mysql_password = config['MYSQL_CONFIG']['mysql.password']
mysql_host_url = config['MYSQL_CONFIG']['mysql.host.url']

type_name = ['date','value','state','id','title','frequency_short','units_short','seasonal_adjustment_short']
type_schema = [Types.STRING(), Types.FLOAT(), Types.STRING(), Types.STRING(), Types.STRING(), Types.STRING(), Types.STRING(), Types.STRING()]
output_type = Types.ROW_NAMED(type_name, type_schema)
type_info = RowTypeInfo(type_schema, type_name)

source = KafkaSource.builder() \
    .set_bootstrap_servers(kafka_brokerlist) \
    .set_topics('topic_' + 'exportGoods') \
    .set_starting_offsets(KafkaOffsetsInitializer.earliest()) \
    .set_value_only_deserializer(SimpleStringSchema()) \
    .build()

ds = env.from_source(source, WatermarkStrategy.no_watermarks(), "Kafka Source")

csv_ds = ds.filter(lambda str: not(str.startswith('date'))).map(CustomCsvMapFunction(), output_type=output_type) 
# csv_ds.print()

jdbcConnOptions = JdbcConnectionOptions.JdbcConnectionOptionsBuilder()\
            .with_url(mysql_host_url)\
            .with_driver_name('com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver')\
            .with_user_name(mysql_user)\
            .with_password(mysql_password)\
            .build()

jdbcExeOptions = JdbcExecutionOptions.builder()\
            .with_batch_interval_ms(1000)\
            .with_batch_size(200)\
            .with_max_retries(5)\
            .build()

csv_ds.add_sink(
    JdbcSink.sink(
            'INSERT INTO ' + 'tbl_' + 'exportGoods' + ' VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)',
            type_info, jdbcConnOptions, jdbcExeOptions))

env.execute('Flink Save2 MySQL')
env.close()

The codes work successfully without exceptions. But I have several kafka topics and corresponding several mysql tables. So I make for-loop of jdbc connectivity like below,
for flink_stream in TITLE_FLINK_STREAM:
    source = KafkaSource.builder() \
        .set_bootstrap_servers(kafka_brokerlist) \
        .set_topics('topic_' + flink_stream.suffix) \
        .set_starting_offsets(KafkaOffsetsInitializer.earliest()) \
        .set_value_only_deserializer(SimpleStringSchema()) \
        .build()

    ds = env.from_source(source, WatermarkStrategy.no_watermarks(), "Kafka Source")

    csv_ds = ds.filter(lambda str: not(str.startswith('date'))).map(CustomCsvMapFunction(), output_type=output_type)  
    # csv_ds.print()

    jdbcConnOptions = JdbcConnectionOptions.JdbcConnectionOptionsBuilder()\
                .with_url(mysql_host_url)\
                .with_driver_name('com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver')\
                .with_user_name(mysql_user)\
                .with_password(mysql_password)\
                .build()

    jdbcExeOptions = JdbcExecutionOptions.builder()\
                .with_batch_interval_ms(1000)\
                .with_batch_size(200)\
                .with_max_retries(5)\
                .build()

    csv_ds.add_sink(
        JdbcSink.sink(
                'INSERT INTO ' + 'tbl_' + flink_stream.suffix + ' VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)',
                type_info, jdbcConnOptions, jdbcExeOptions))


env.execute('Flink Save2 MySQL')
env.close()

The insertion of data are done successfully for a while, but the loop codes is interrupted and throw the following exceptions.
Exception in thread read_grpc_client_inputs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 1045, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 982, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/joseph/VSCode_Workspace/.venv-etl/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/data_plane.py", line 669, in <lambda>
    target=lambda: self._read_inputs(elements_iterator),
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/joseph/VSCode_Workspace/.venv-etl/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/data_plane.py", line 652, in _read_inputs
    for elements in elements_iterator:
  File "/home/joseph/VSCode_Workspace/.venv-etl/lib/python3.11/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 543, in __next__
    return self._next()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/joseph/VSCode_Workspace/.venv-etl/lib/python3.11/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 969, in _next
    raise self
grpc._channel._MultiThreadedRendezvous: <_MultiThreadedRendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
        status = StatusCode.CANCELLED
        details = "Multiplexer hanging up"
        debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:Error received from peer ipv6:%5B::1%5D:37507 {created_time:"2024-09-28T16:52:35.651536993+09:00", grpc_status:1, grpc_message:"Multiplexer hanging up"}"
>
Exception in thread read_grpc_client_inputs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 1045, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 982, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/joseph/VSCode_Workspace/.venv-etl/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/data_plane.py", line 669, in <lambda>
    target=lambda: self._read_inputs(elements_iterator),
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/joseph/VSCode_Workspace/.venv-etl/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/data_plane.py", line 652, in _read_inputs
    for elements in elements_iterator:
  File "/home/joseph/VSCode_Workspace/.venv-etl/lib/python3.11/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 543, in __next__
    return self._next()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/joseph/VSCode_Workspace/.venv-etl/lib/python3.11/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 969, in _next
    raise self
grpc._channel._MultiThreadedRendezvous: <_MultiThreadedRendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
        status = StatusCode.CANCELLED
        details = "Multiplexer hanging up"
        debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:Error received from peer ipv6:%5B::1%5D:46051 {grpc_message:"Multiplexer hanging up", grpc_status:1, created_time:"2024-09-28T16:52:35.83112255+09:00"}"
>
Exception in thread read_grpc_client_inputs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 1045, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 982, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/joseph/VSCode_Workspace/.venv-etl/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/data_plane.py", line 669, in <lambda>
    target=lambda: self._read_inputs(elements_iterator),
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/joseph/VSCode_Workspace/.venv-etl/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/data_plane.py", line 652, in _read_inputs
    for elements in elements_iterator:
  File "/home/joseph/VSCode_Workspace/.venv-etl/lib/python3.11/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 543, in __next__
    return self._next()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/joseph/VSCode_Workspace/.venv-etl/lib/python3.11/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 969, in _next
    raise self
grpc._channel._MultiThreadedRendezvous: <_MultiThreadedRendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
        status = StatusCode.CANCELLED
        details = "Multiplexer hanging up"
        debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:Error received from peer ipv6:%5B::1%5D:44919 {created_time:"2024-09-28T16:52:35.970579357+09:00", grpc_status:1, grpc_message:"Multiplexer hanging up"}"
>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/joseph/VSCode_Workspace/etl-stream-python/com/aaa/etl/jdbctest.py", line 116, in <module>
    env.execute('Flink Save2 MySQL')
  File "/home/joseph/VSCode_Workspace/.venv-etl/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyflink/datastream/stream_execution_environment.py", line 824, in execute
    return JobExecutionResult(self._j_stream_execution_environment.execute(j_stream_graph))
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/joseph/VSCode_Workspace/.venv-etl/lib/python3.11/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1322, in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/joseph/VSCode_Workspace/.venv-etl/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyflink/util/exceptions.py", line 146, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/joseph/VSCode_Workspace/.venv-etl/lib/python3.11/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
    raise Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o10.execute.
: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobResult.toJobExecutionResult(JobResult.java:144)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.minicluster.MiniClusterJobClient.lambda$getJobExecutionResult$3(MiniClusterJobClient.java:141)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:646)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:510)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2147)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.pekko.PekkoInvocationHandler.lambda$invokeRpc$1(PekkoInvocationHandler.java:268)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:863)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:841)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:510)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2147)
        at org.apache.flink.util.concurrent.FutureUtils.doForward(FutureUtils.java:1287)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.ClassLoadingUtils.lambda$null$1(ClassLoadingUtils.java:93)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.ClassLoadingUtils.runWithContextClassLoader(ClassLoadingUtils.java:68)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.ClassLoadingUtils.lambda$guardCompletionWithContextClassLoader$2(ClassLoadingUtils.java:92)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:863)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:841)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:510)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2147)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.pekko.ScalaFutureUtils$1.onComplete(ScalaFutureUtils.java:47)
        at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.OnComplete.internal(Future.scala:310)
        at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.OnComplete.internal(Future.scala:307)
        at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.japi$CallbackBridge.apply(Future.scala:234)
        at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.japi$CallbackBridge.apply(Future.scala:231)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:64)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.pekko.ScalaFutureUtils$DirectExecutionContext.execute(ScalaFutureUtils.java:65)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:72)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.$anonfun$tryComplete$1(Promise.scala:288)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.$anonfun$tryComplete$1$adapted(Promise.scala:288)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:288)
        at org.apache.pekko.pattern.PromiseActorRef.$bang(AskSupport.scala:629)
        at org.apache.pekko.pattern.PipeToSupport$PipeableFuture$$anonfun$pipeTo$1.applyOrElse(PipeToSupport.scala:34)
        at org.apache.pekko.pattern.PipeToSupport$PipeableFuture$$anonfun$pipeTo$1.applyOrElse(PipeToSupport.scala:33)
        at scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$andThen$1(Future.scala:536)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.liftedTree1$1(Promise.scala:33)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transform$1(Promise.scala:33)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:64)
        at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:73)
        at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.$anonfun$run$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:110)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:85)
        at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:110)
        at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:59)
        at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$PekkoForkJoinTask.exec(ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator.scala:57)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:373)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1182)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1655)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1622)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:165)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.JobException: Recovery is suppressed by NoRestartBackoffTimeStrategy
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.ExecutionFailureHandler.handleFailure(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:219)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.ExecutionFailureHandler.handleFailureAndReport(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:166)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.ExecutionFailureHandler.getFailureHandlingResult(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:121)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.recordTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:281)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.handleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:272)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.onTaskFailed(DefaultScheduler.java:265)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.onTaskExecutionStateUpdate(SchedulerBase.java:787)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerBase.java:764)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerNG.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerNG.java:83)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.updateTaskExecutionState(JobMaster.java:515)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor31.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:569)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.pekko.PekkoRpcActor.lambda$handleRpcInvocation$1(PekkoRpcActor.java:318)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.ClassLoadingUtils.runWithContextClassLoader(ClassLoadingUtils.java:83)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.pekko.PekkoRpcActor.handleRpcInvocation(PekkoRpcActor.java:316)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.pekko.PekkoRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(PekkoRpcActor.java:229)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.pekko.FencedPekkoRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(FencedPekkoRpcActor.java:88)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.pekko.PekkoRpcActor.handleMessage(PekkoRpcActor.java:174)
        at org.apache.pekko.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:33)
        at org.apache.pekko.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:29)
        at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:127)
        at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse$(PartialFunction.scala:126)
        at org.apache.pekko.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:29)
        at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:175)
        at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:176)
        at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:176)
        at org.apache.pekko.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:547)
        at org.apache.pekko.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:545)
        at org.apache.pekko.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:229)
        at org.apache.pekko.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:590)
        at org.apache.pekko.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:557)
        at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:280)
        at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:241)
        at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:253)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to deserialize consumer record due to
        at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.reader.KafkaRecordEmitter.emitRecord(KafkaRecordEmitter.java:56)
        at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.reader.KafkaRecordEmitter.emitRecord(KafkaRecordEmitter.java:33)
        at org.apache.flink.connector.base.source.reader.SourceReaderBase.pollNext(SourceReaderBase.java:203)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.SourceOperator.emitNext(SourceOperator.java:422)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamTaskSourceInput.emitNext(StreamTaskSourceInput.java:68)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamOneInputProcessor.processInput(StreamOneInputProcessor.java:65)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.processInput(StreamTask.java:638)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.MailboxProcessor.runMailboxLoop(MailboxProcessor.java:231)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.runMailboxLoop(StreamTask.java:973)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:917)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.runWithSystemExitMonitoring(Task.java:970)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.restoreAndInvoke(Task.java:949)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:763)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:575)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.ExceptionInChainedOperatorException: Could not forward element to next operator
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(CopyingChainingOutput.java:92)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.collect(CopyingChainingOutput.java:50)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.collect(CopyingChainingOutput.java:29)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SourceOperatorStreamTask$AsyncDataOutputToOutput.emitRecord(SourceOperatorStreamTask.java:310)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.source.SourceOutputWithWatermarks.collect(SourceOutputWithWatermarks.java:110)
        at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.reader.KafkaRecordEmitter$SourceOutputWrapper.collect(KafkaRecordEmitter.java:67)
        at org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.DeserializationSchema.deserialize(DeserializationSchema.java:84)
        at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.reader.deserializer.KafkaValueOnlyDeserializationSchemaWrapper.deserialize(KafkaValueOnlyDeserializationSchemaWrapper.java:51)
        at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.reader.KafkaRecordEmitter.emitRecord(KafkaRecordEmitter.java:53)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.ExceptionInChainedOperatorException: Could not forward element to next operator
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(CopyingChainingOutput.java:92)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.collect(CopyingChainingOutput.java:50)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.ChainingOutput.collectAndCheckIfChained(ChainingOutput.java:90)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.ChainingOutput.collectAndCheckIfChained(ChainingOutput.java:40)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.BroadcastingOutputCollector.collect(BroadcastingOutputCollector.java:83)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.BroadcastingOutputCollector.collect(BroadcastingOutputCollector.java:34)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.TimestampedCollector.collect(TimestampedCollector.java:52)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.python.process.collector.RunnerOutputCollector.collect(RunnerOutputCollector.java:52)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.python.process.AbstractExternalOneInputPythonFunctionOperator.emitResult(AbstractExternalOneInputPythonFunctionOperator.java:133)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.python.process.AbstractExternalPythonFunctionOperator.emitResults(AbstractExternalPythonFunctionOperator.java:142)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.python.process.AbstractExternalPythonFunctionOperator.invokeFinishBundle(AbstractExternalPythonFunctionOperator.java:101)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.python.AbstractPythonFunctionOperator.checkInvokeFinishBundleByCount(AbstractPythonFunctionOperator.java:292)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.python.process.AbstractExternalOneInputPythonFunctionOperator.processElement(AbstractExternalOneInputPythonFunctionOperator.java:146)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.python.process.ExternalPythonProcessOperator.processElement(ExternalPythonProcessOperator.java:112)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(CopyingChainingOutput.java:75)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.apache.flink.types.Row.getFieldNames(boolean)" because "from" is null
        at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.RowSerializer.copy(RowSerializer.java:137)
        at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.RowSerializer.copy(RowSerializer.java:69)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(CopyingChainingOutput.java:74)

Are these exceptions due to the Flink configuration errors? The exceptions seem not to be codes grammars mismatches. Then do I have to change the configuration of Flink? For your information, I made the Flink java sdk codes having similar architecture and those codes work without exceptions.
== Updated Parts
I found some interesting fact. The above exception was thrown at the exact 7000 input lines. Whenever the 7001th line of csv-type data was about to be inserted to mysql, the errors occured. I think the some type of limitation prevent the insertion of 7000 more data into mysql and this is the matter of configuration. I increased the with_batch_size function parameter, but the same errors were thrown. Any idea?
